# Karma opens three times in Chrome. Karma Bug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, karma-runner

For some reason, Karma tries three times to open Chrome, and thinks it's unsuccessful. It works fine once it loads, and shows that it connects on two sockets.

I have Chrome installed in a different location than Karma defaults to, so I had to link to the absolute path of Chrome. I suspect this may have something to do with why it doesn't "see" that Chrome is running. Is this a bug or is there something I can do to fix this?

Here is my config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    '../../Scripts/angular.js',
    '../../Scripts/angular-*.js',
    '*.spec.js',
    '*.js'
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
  '../../Scripts/angular-scenario.js',
],


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,

// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers: ["C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"],

// If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
captureTimeout: 60000,

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun: false
});
};
```

Comment: still a good question in 2018!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, closing the browser window by pressing the X button would cause this issue to occur. There is a flag called retryLimit which is set to 2 by default, see http://karma-runner.github.io/2.0/config/configuration-file.html.

If you set that to zero, by adding the line

```
retryLimit : 0,
```

somewhere in your config.set structure, the browser doesn't pop up after you close it. Though, the fact that that flag exists makes me think that you are normally supposed to close karma by some other means...

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of providing the absolute path, you should set the path to chrome binary in your environmental variables.
You can set it manually, or follow the instructions here: 
http://karma-runner.github.io/2.0/config/browsers.html

Comment: You, should include those instructions here, external links should only provide additional information or be a source refenrece.

Comment: Setting the path to the binary depends on what platform you are using. For example on Windows: C:> SET CHROME_BIN=<your installation path>